# How to post Content-disposition with json request from Postman

Tags: java, rest, postman

I have below request, I want to send the POST request from the postman.
-----------------------------315944029337182016342480456440
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Unnnn.json"
Content-Type: application/json

{"version":"22.12","applications":"89fdjh-8jja-2hbansb"}
-----------------------------315944029337182016342480456440--

Please guide me how to set these param in postman and get the response

Comment: -----------------------------315944029337182016342480456440

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Unnnn.json"
Content-Type: application/json


{"version":"22.12","applications":"89fdjh-8jja-2hbansb"}

-----------------------------315944029337182016342480456440--

Comment: Send a multipart request (a.k.a Form request), where it allows you to add key-value pairs and upload files. What you are showing is how a raw multipart request looks like. Postman will format it for you